# Gstreamer rtsp stream to appsink to openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I need a bit of your help because I'm trying to receive rtsp stream by gstreamer and then put it into openCV to process video. What is worse, I will need it back from openCV but first things first. I'm quite new to this so I don't know Gstreamer well so I'm counting on you guys. Some simple examples would be best but I'll use what I have;) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do with opencv? Some of its features are already wrapped in gstreamer. Depending on what you want to do you could have opencv called from a gstreamer plugin rather than taking buffers out of the pipeline and then pushing it back into another one.

Comment: I need to receive rtsp stream with gstreamer, copy it like 3 times, one would be restream with rtspStream, one would be saved to file, and one has to be convert to cv::Mat. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
uridecodebin uri=rtsp:// name=uridec ! queue ! tee name=t ! queue ! <some encoder and muxer> ! filesink t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw, format=BGR" ! appsink t. ! queue ! <restream>
```

In this possible solution you are receiving and decoding at uridecodebin which means that for re-streaming you need to encode, as well as encoding for storing to a file. If that's not what you want you can replace uridecodebin with rtspsrc that will give you RTP streams instead of decoded raw streams. Something like:

```
rtspsrc ! rtpXdepay ! tee name=t ! ...
```

Replace X with the format you are receiving (can be done dynamically from your application). Now the output is an encoded stream that you can use in a similar way as the sample pipeline above.

Note that these suggestions are assuming your rtsp input is a single stream (video likely), if you want video and audio you need to add 2 branches out of uridecodebin or rtspsrc. I also assumed that by 'rtspStream' is some sort of external library/application that you are going to use to retransmit instead of using gstreamer itself. In any way, this should give you an idea.